# Dynamically Allocating Array With Datafile

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic-allocation

On a C++ project, I have been trying to use an array to store data from a textfile that I would later use. I have been having problems initializing the array without a size. Here is a basic sample of what I have been doing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    ifstream usern;
    string data;
    string otherdata;
    string *users = nullptr;


    usern.open("users.txt");

    while(usern >> otherdata)
        i++;

    users = new (nothrow) string[i];

    for (int n = 0; usern >> data; n++)
    {
        users[n] = data;
    }


    usern.close();
    return 0;
}
```

This is a pretty rough example that I threw together. Basically I try to read the items from a text file called `users.txt` and store them in an array. I used pointers in the example that I included (which probably wasn't the best idea considering I don't know too much about poniters). When I run this program, regardless of the data in the file, I do not get any result when I try to test the values by including `cout << *(users + 1)`. It just leaves a blank line in the window. I am guessing my error is in my use of pointers or in how I am assigning values in the pointers themselves. I was wondering if anybody could **point** me in the right direction on how to get the correct values into an array. Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell us a bit about the format of the file?? e.g. is it a `.csv`, `.xml`, `.tsv` or one user per line etc??

Comment: Also I would recommend using std::vector for something like this as it allows for dynamic size reallocation without the need for you to be using pointers??

Comment: The file given is a .txt that consists of 3 strings of text, but ideally the number of strings can be altered and still work. Also, this is a small piece of an assignment where we are not allowed to use vectors anywhere. If we were, I wouldn't have any problems because vectors make much more sense to me!

Comment: I would include that in your question (as an edit) otherwise just about everyone is going to tell you to use a vector :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reopening usern after

```
    while(usern >> otherdata)
    i++;
```

perhaps, try putting in

```
usern.close();
ifstream usern2;
usern2.open("users.txt");
```

right after that.

There may be other issues, but this seems like the most likely one to me. Let me know if you find success with this. To me it appears like usern is already reaching eof, and then you try to read from it a second time.

One thing that helps me a lot in finding such issues is to just put a cout << "looping"; or something inside the for loop so you know that you're at least getting in that for loop.

You can also do the same thing with usern.seekg(0, ios::beg);

Comment: That took care of the problem! Never thought about having to open it up twice. Thank you for the advice!

Comment: Would recommend using seekg instead of closing and reopening??

Answer (score 0):

What I think has happened in your code is that you have moved the pointer in the file that shows where the file is being read from. This happened when you iterated the number of strings to be read in using the code below.

```
while(usern >> otherdata)
    i++;
```

This however brought the file pointer to the end of the file this means that in order to read the file you need to move the file pointer to the beginning of the file before you re-read it into your array of strings that you allocated of size `i`. This can be acheived by adding `usern.seekg(0, ios::beg);` after your while loop, as shown below. (For a good tutorial on file pointers see [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/137-random-file-io/).)

```
while(usern >> otherdata)
    i++;

// Returns file pointer to beginning of file.
usern.seekg(0, ios::beg);

// The rest of your code.
```

**Warning:** I am unsure about how safe dynamically allocating STL containers are, I have previously run into issues with code similar to yours and would recommend staying away from this in functional code.